# OCR pytesseract, recognize the biggest word in an image

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr

I'm using **pytesseract** to recognize text from an image, is there anyway i can detect/recognize the biggest word in that image

[image]

In the image above, i'm trying to detect/recognize "Atacand Plus" which is the biggest words in the whole image in size. I tried to apply filters like sharppen, smooth, and Max filter and repeated them many times between 5-10 times depends on the picture, to remove the smaller words, but is there any other way to do it?

Thanks,
Reagards

Comment: You mean the longest word as in most characters?  Could you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, i'm trying to detect/recognize the biggest word in size of an image, i'll attach a photo and explain, thank you sir